# ¿Como almacenar elementos en un array en php que recibo desde un formulario html?

Tags: php, html, array

Tengo el siguiente problema: tengo un formulario en html el cual tiene los campos nombre y teléfono. Cada vez que el usuario rellena esto y pulsa enviar, estos tienen que ir a un array en php para ir mostrando dichos datos según se almacenan. El problema es que cada vez que pulso enviar y muestra los datos, solo se ve el último nombre y teléfono agregado.

El código es este:

```
<form name="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <p>
        <label for="n">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" id="n" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="a">Tel&eacute;fono: </label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="60" name="telefono" id="t" placeholder="telefono">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Añadir contacto" name="anadir">&nbsp;&nbsp;           
        <input type="reset" value="Limpiar campos" />
    </p>
   
    </fieldset>
  <!---  <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 5px">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" value="Limpiar" />
    </div>-->
</form>
```

Y el de PHP es este:

```
   <?php
  $nombrePersona = $_POST['nombre'];
  $telefonoPersona = $_POST['telefono'];
  $i=0;
  $j=0;
  $nombres = array ();
  $telefonos =array();

  $nombres[$i] = $nombrePersona;
  $telefonoPersona[$j] = $telefonoPersona;

  $i++;
  $j++;
 
  echo "<br>----------------<br>";
  var_dump($nombres);
  var_dump($telefonos);
  echo "<br>----------------<br>";


?>
```

Ya he intentado de todo, arrays con claves, variable de sesión pero sigue igual, solo almacena un dato. Soy muy nueva en php y no se muy bien como va

Comment: Bueno, primero que nada, nunca estás cargando nada nuevo. Pones $i y $j en 0 cada vez que haces el envío, por lo que siempre sobrescribes el primer dato. Deberías en vez de, sobrescribir una posición, hacer el uso del método `array_push()` para que este agregue valores nuevos al array. [link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php)

Comment: También lo he intentado con array_push y vuelvo a tener el mismo problema, imagino que es porque cada vez que hago submit el array se vuelve a declarar. ¿Como puedo evitar esto?

Comment: Debes guardar los datos en algún lado, ya sea en variables de sesión, archivo de texto, base de datos, etc.

Comment: Controlando la existencia de este mismo. En un inicio, jamás existirá hasta el PHP. Pero como siempre lo declaras nuevamente, este, se resetea. Sugiero usar otro tipo de variable para el array en sí, y de este modo que exista siempre. Ya sea con el uso de sesiones, base de datos, etc.